# writing a script/Function for checkboxes and Custom Delete button in Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: json, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I need help writing a script/Function for my Telerik UI for asp.net MVC program. I have a delete button in my tool bar and I think my script is correct for it deleting. Now, I'm told that my check boxes haft to have a script also to be deleted when checked. As a C# coder, I'm not entirely knowledgeable about Json coding. So, any help would be appreciated! Here is my code below.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MVCSQLDatabase.Models>()
      .Name("Grid")
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .PageSize(10)
          .Batch(true)
          .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Proposal_Uid))
          .Read(read => read.Action("Proposals_Read", "Grid"))
          .Create(create => create.Action("Proposals_Create", "Grid"))
          .Update(update => update.Action("Proposals_Update", "Grid"))
          .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Proposals_Destroy", "Grid"))
      )
          .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))

      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Select().Width(100); //<-- my check boxes code.
          columns.Bound(c => c.Prime).Width(215);
          columns.Bound(c => c.Proposal).Width(200);
          columns.Bound(c => c.C).Width(190);
          columns.Bound(c => c.Cl).Width(185);
          columns.Bound(c => c.T).Width(290);
          columns.Bound(c => c.M).Width(220);
          columns.Bound(c => c.S).Format("{0: dd/MM/yyyy}").Width(170);
          columns.Bound(c => c.E).Format("{0: dd/MM/yyyy}").Width(170);
          columns.Bound(c => c.P).Width(235);
          columns.Bound(c => c.Con).Width(215);
          columns.Command(command => { command.Destroy(); }).Width(180);// <--- My delete button in my column
      })
      .ToolBar(toolbar =>
          {
          toolbar.Create();
          toolbar.Save();
          toolbar.Excel();
          toolbar.Custom().Text("Delete").Name("batchDestroy").IconClass("k-icon k-i-close"); //<-- my custom made delete button in my toolbar.
      })
      .ColumnMenu()
      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
      .Pageable()
      .Selectable(selectable =>
          {
          selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple);
          selectable.Type(GridSelectionType.Row);
      })
      .PersistSelection()
      .Filterable(filterable => filterable.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
      .Scrollable()
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:835px;" })

)

    <script>
        $("#grid").on("click", "batchDestroy", function() {
        var $tr = $(this).closest("tr"),
        grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid"),
        dataItem = grid.dataItem($tr);
        grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Your event should get the selected items `var selectedItems = grid.selectedKeyNames();` then iterate through them and delete. Your code is just removing from the grid - not the database.You could make an AJAX call to an action that takes a single id or better yet an array of all the IDs to remove. Then refresh the grid on success.

Comment: So it would look like this? `$("#grid").on("click", "batchDestroy", function() {
        var selectedItems  = grid.selectedKeyNames();,
        grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid"),
        dataItem = grid.dataItem(selectedItems);;
        grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);`

Comment: No. More like [this](https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-remove-mutiple-selected-rows)

Comment: Unfortunately, that's for checkrows and not check boxes. Apparently, in the Telerik world they are very different and as such need to be coded differently. It's crazy. I have yet to find a answer that works for me.

Comment: It's the same concept. Only the UI is different (check boxes versus row selection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for anybody else stuck in this situation. The thing that got me the most, was the .done function to end the button click function and then saving the grid AFTER the delete was made. Hopefully, this helps others!

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $(".k-grid-Destroy").on("click", function (e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
                var selectedRows = grid.select();
                kendo.confirm(kendo.format("Are you sure you wish to delete {0} records?", selectedRows.length))
                    .done(function ()
                    {
                        $.each(selectedRows, function (i, row)
                        {
                            grid.removeRow(row);
                        })
                        grid.saveChanges();
                    });
            });
        });
    </script>
```